# logical && in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

The logical `&&` operator executes the expression to its left; and only if it is true, it executes the expression on the right hand side.

But in the following example,

![C Short-Circuit AND Example][1]

if the LHS is false and the RHS isn't executed then it violates the prcedence order of operators in C because unary NOT has greater precedence over logical `&&`:

![C Operator Precedence Summary][2]

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Operator precedence only affects binding, not order of evaluation. And please do not post images instead of code. Especially unintelligible ones.

Comment: That's the way the && operator works. When the left hand expression is false, the the right hand expression is not evaluated. In your case the right hand expression is `!(a == -1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this expression:

```
a*b + c*d
```

Which order is it executed? Well, we know that the `+` must be executed last, but there is *no information* here about which multiply happens first.

It could do this:

```
t1 = a * b
t2 = c * d
result = t1 + t2
```

Or, it could do this:

```
t1 = c * d
t2 = a * b
result = t1 + t2
```

There's no way to know.

Now consider this expression:

```
a>1 && b<2
```

*Logically* speaking, there's no reason why this needs any specific evaluation order either. It could happen either way around, and it would make no difference.

BUT, sometimes it is important what order the sub-expressions are evaluated:

```
ptr != NULL && ptr->value == 1
```

So, as a *convenience* C **defines** that the `&&` operator has special behaviour that guarantees the evaluation order.

If C were *not* defined this way, then we'd have to write everything like this:

```
if (ptr != NULL)
  if (ptr->value == 1)
    result = true
```

And that would be a PITA!

There is another reason, besides mere textual convenience though: optimization.

When one half of an `&&` expression evaluates to false, there's no reason to check the result of the other half: it would just be a waste of time, and electricity. So, the compiler wants to short-cut it.

Except that compiler *can't* delete anything that might have user-visible (or programmer-visible) side-effects, unless the programmer *knows* it's going to happen.

So, again, the behaviour must be well defined: left then right. If it were not then it might change behaviour when optimized, and that would be bad.

Answer (score 2):

The logic behind the and operator operating from left to right and short circuiting when one evaluates to false is for a few reasons, one being that evaluating the second after the first evaluted to false is a waste of effort as the entire condition will never evaluate to True after one has evaluated to false, it is also so that you can do things like order your conditions in ways that will prevent errors, for example:  (sorry for the python in your C question but it is what came to mind first)

```
if 'parameter' in dictionary and dictionary['parameter']:
    (do something with parameter that you are now confident exists AND has a value);
```

whereas if you reversed the order

```
if dictionary['parameter'] and 'parameter' in dictionary:
```

could potentially throw an error because asking for the value of 'parameter' in a dictionary where it does not exist is a no-no.

Again, sorry for the python but I hope you get the jist of why this functionality is to your advantage and available to be leveraged by the savvy coder.